# Get google maps small portion for offline application

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, google-maps-api

Can some body help me in downloading some portion of hybrid maps of google as I want to store them in my server and display them on web application using openlayers so that the user will only have access to only that particular area, not the whole map

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your Question to provide more details like whether the Android application you mention has a name that people here are likely to be familiar with, please?  The more relevant information that you can provide in your Question the more likely it is that you will receive an appropriate Answer.

Comment: Sir I have edited..

Answer (score 2):

Google does not allow caching of tiles. But there are sources for tiles you can use, such as Open Street Map, and Open MapQuest. But you'll need to download and store lots of tiles depending on the size of your area and whether you allow zooming. Open Street Map has limits on the number of tiles you can download in a batch. Open MapQuest is a bit more flexible.

Comment: MapQuest Open is no longer a source for free tiles. However, ESRI has a number of tile sets available, such as "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"

Answer (score 1):

Downloading of tiles is not allowed by the Google Maps terms of use.

You can limite the map extent of map by passing a maxExtent to the constructor.

Could not understand the reason for download since a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google doesn't allow users download tiles and you're using a server for your web application, why don't let your server download the part of google map your user is interested to each time he needs it?

Or maybe try to explain better you request, probably you want to make some kind of offline maps application, I don't know...